# AVRCP target role

Tags: bluetooth, target, bluez, avrcp

I'm trying to implement an AVRCP target profile using Bluez 5.23. Essentially I need to be able to modify absolute volume (in a TG role) and receive play/pause events from the controller, an iPhone. I can't find any documentation on how to do this. Does anybody have any pointers?
Thanks,

Comment: have you got solution  for this.

Comment: I haven't. I noticed that some of the products in the marked (car audio) also don't support it. My guess is that one needs to support a specific profile such as hands free in order for the CT to listen for the changes.

Comment: I have a hardware, I can pair my iPhone with the hardware. but, I need to send signals to hardware.

Comment: What signals are you trying to send? Volume change? You will have to implement the bluez interface containing the volume up/down methods in order to receive those events on the hardware. You will also have to set the right device class (bluez config file or through the agent interface) and UUID.

Comment: there are two ways to change the volume, via the transport using an absolute value, and the second through the up/down commands. The transport volume is a property and you will have to register to listen to changes to that property. If the iphone uses transport volume, I would think the samples would already be attenuated and you would not need to do anything on the hardware. Do you have a display on the hardware and want to show the volume level?